# How to write a CSS Conditional in ember for class attributes?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

am stuck on a problem and haven't been able to find a resource that explains this. Sorry if this is obvious but I am an ember newbie.

I want to be able to write an if equals conditional for a table.

Example:

```
if (data === 'r') {
     change table row to red
else 
    change table row to blue
}
```

I've been trying by using the following code:

```
<table class="attr1 {{#if (eq data 'r')}} red {{else}} blue {{/if}}">
</table>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To switch the class, use `if` handlebars. [Docs for Reference](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/templates/conditionals/)

`{{if <property> <if true, inserts class1> <if false, inserts class2}}`

**application.hbs**

```
<table class='{{if usered "red" "blue"}}'>
    <tr><td>A</td></tr>
    <tr><td>B</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C</td></tr>
</table>
```

**application.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: 'Ember Twiddle',
  usered: false,
  actions:{
        changeColor : function(){
            this.toggleProperty("usered");
      }
  }
});
```

**app.css**

```
.red
{
  color:red;
}
.blue
{
  color: blue;
}

table, tr, td
{
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

[Refer this Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/33c762516f11d674ac3203ae673b099c?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C) for example.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. My understanding is this works if you value is true or false but what if the value in the database is specific, how would you go about something like that?